# Apple seedling starting to die

Tags: diagnosis, apples

I read the other post about the apple seedling dying and my situation is similar. I grew the seedling from an apple from the store. I had grown it to about 11 inches (30 cm) and all of a sudden the leaves went from green to brown. I don’t know why. I tried less water, more water, less sun, and more sun. What can I do?

I have attached a picture.

[image]

Comment: Two obvious factors: Fairly small pot for a tree, and deciduous trees lose their leaves in fall. Third factor - the flowers are a pretty strong indication that the apple seed did not sprout (unsurprising, without stratification) but a weed seed did.

Comment: Just as an FYI, an apple tree grown from an apple you bought from a store will likely NOT produce the same quality of fruit as you purchased.   Almost all commercial apples are from trees grown from cuttings so that the genetic mix is the same as from the original tree so that they will produce the same quality of fruit.   The seeds are NOT genetically the same, even if both parent trees were of the same type of apple.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson In point of actual practice, almost all commercial apple trees are grafted top to selected cloned rootstocks, not grown from cuttings. The rootstocks are choosen for desired characteristics as are the fruiting varieties for the tops.

Comment: @Ecnerwal So cuttings of one for the top grafted to cuttings of another after developing it into rootstocks?

Comment: @Ecnerwal, are you sure it’s a weed? I asked a friend (who grew up on a farm) before it had issues and she confirmed it was an apple tree seedling.

Comment: Yes. It has a cluster of flowerbuds on the top of it. Even if you are in the Southern hemisphere, they don't look like apple blossom buds. And in the Northern hemisphere, it's quite utterly the wrong time of year, plus they still don't look like apple blossom buds do. Add in a nice clear picture of a flower when one opens and someone might be able to identify the thing (please add location in the world, as well, to help that along.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal. I am in Dallas, TX. I will add another picture once a bud blossoms.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson A very high proportion of fruit trees have a prominent bulge near ground level which is the location of the graft. Same applies to roses, which are of course closely related to apples.

Answer (score 15):

It's not an apple seedling; the flower buds indicate that it's some sort of other seed that sprouted in your pot and has been taking advantage of you thinking it's an apple seedling.

Comment: Could this be plant mimicry?

Comment: It's a cuckoo plant :-)

Answer (score 0):

Until you know better, assume that it's in the nightshade family and wash your hands after handling.